# How to add src path into vue component from json file

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vue-cli, vue-loader

How to render images, if i get path from json file. Default i use `require('../assets/img/item-image.png')`. But i have no idea, how use it in this case

Component:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
    <img :src="item.src">
</div>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        name: 'componentName',
        data () {
            return {
                items: null   
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            axios
            .get('./test.json')
            .then(response => (this.items = response.data))
        }
    }
</script>
```

JSON file:

```
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "item title",
            "src": "../assets/img/item-image.png",
            "alt": "item-image",
            "text": "item body"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Are all the image paths starting with `../assets/img`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add `require`

```
<img :src="require(item.src)">
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. Without knowing anything about where the images are located, Webpack won't be able to bundle them

Comment: In this case, you can put images in the public folder. But you have to make sure that these images don't change often due to caching issues.

Comment: Excellent point but you don't need to use `require` for things in the `public` folder

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep using `require()` in order to let Webpack know to include your images when bundling.

Because Webpack bundles at compile time and your images are only known at runtime, this is best done by keeping part of the path static so Webpack can optimistically include the right files.

For example, if all your images are under `../assets/img`, the best option would look like this

```js
async mounted () {
  const pathRegex = /^\.\.\/assets\/img\//
  const { data } = await axios.get("./test.json")
  this.items = data.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    src: require(`../assets/img/${item.src.replace(pathRegex, "")}`)
  }))
}
```

Webpack will then bundle every file under `../assets/img` and at runtime, will be able to resolve the paths you supply.

See https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression

Comment: I am getting this error: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: @NwaiwuIsidore it's not possible to debug that issue from a single comment. I suggest you post a new question

Comment: I found a way by using map(). I will post it as a possible answer.

Answer (score -1):

This was how I solved it. I kept getting an error when using the regex above to add `require` to the src attribute in the json. This is what I did instead and it worked for me.

I am using `fetch()` to read the json which I am watching with `json-server`. The json is basically an array (cokeImages) of objects when you use `res.json()` to convert it.

```
{
  "cokeImages": [
            { 
                "title": "Cocacola Life", 
                "description": "Lorem ipsum no sicut anon in aquila no ager. In homines ad majorem tempus avis, et cum in pecunia imoten tua",
                "src": "../assets/cocacola-cans/cocacola-life.png", 
                "id": 1, 
                "name": "cocacola-life",
                "nutrition": [
                    { "title": "sodium", "value": "150 cl", "percent": "25%" },
                    { "title": "Total Fats", "value": "0g", "percent" : "0%" },
                    { "title": "sodium (mg)", "value": "40mg", "percent": "0%"},
                    { "title": "potasium", "value": "4g", "percent": "0%" },
                    { "title": "calcium", "value": "0g", "percent": "0%"}
                ]
            },
            { 
                "title": "Cocacola Zero", 
                "description": "Lorem ipsum no sicut anon in aquila no ager. In homines ad majorem tempus avis, et cum in pecunia imoten tua",
                "src": "../assets/cocacola-cans/cocacola-zero.png", 
                "id": 2, 
                "name": "cocacola-zero",
               ... (and so on)...
```

as you can see, the name property in each object is also the name I used in each images `src`.
It is that name property I used in the `map()` method to attach `require` to each src.

```
mounted(){
      fetch("http://localhost:3000/cokeImages")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(arrayOfOjects => {
        console.log(arrayOfObjects)
        this.cokeImages = data.map(eachObject => {
          return {...eachObject, src: require(`../assets/cocacola-cans/${eachObject.name}.png`)}
        })
        console.log(this.cokeImages)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message)
      })
    }
```